# On Chrome, in SignalR after pressing ctrl+F5 Hub method get invoked before connection is connected

Tags: websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

I have added code in connection.start().done().
Still it is happening while complete refresh in chrome.

```
   var connection = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath:false });
   var hub = connection.createHubProxy('Hub');
   connection.start().done(function (){
   hub.invoke('method', page, false).done(function (data) {
   //code
    });
 });
```

Comment: I had this behaviour, turned out that I had an old version still in the scripts folder, and the ASP.NET script bundle loaded both, which resulted in this side effect

Comment: I have upgrade to signalR latest version 2.2.0 , and update bundling. Still getting this issue

Comment: Ok, so you do not have dynamic bundling but static rather?

Comment: yes its static, on page load it get binds one time

Comment: Strange I have very similar code that works for my project https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.JS/jquery.signalR.eventAggregator.js#L157   You can try here in chrome and it works http://malmgrens.org/signalr/